# Android phone number format in listview not working

Tags: android, listviewitem

My ListView is not formating phone numbers even using

`numberField.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());`

Java Code

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
        TextView numberField = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.callnum_cl);
        numberField.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
        numberField.setText(number);
}
```

calllog_list_item.xml

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/callnum_cl"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:gravity="top"
     android:inputType="phone"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:text="@string/phone_number" />
```

Comment: It is working when I remove line android:text="@string/phone_number"

Comment: add a solution to your post

Answer (score 1):

Try to use another approach with [PhoneNuberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html)

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
        TextView numberField = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.callnum_cl);
        numberField.setText(PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(number));
}
```

UPDATE

You can try to use library from Google [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

See [formatOutOfCountryCallingNumber](https://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html#formatOutOfCountryCallingNumber(PhoneNumber,%20java.lang.String)) method

Comment: It is only formating US numbers but not working for Inadian numbers

Answer (score 0):

android:text="@string/phone_number"

Adding above line, `numberField.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher())`; will not work. As you are setting TextChangeListener dynamically on the textview while binding the listview. You need to remove `android:text="@string/phone_number`" from xml file. it will work then.